# Apply GIF to SCNPlane

Tags: swift, scenekit, gif, arkit, scnnode

Right now my Swift code creates a `SCNPlane` with an image called `we.jpg`. What I would like to do is to replace `we.jpg` with a `ball.gif`. `material.diffuse.contents` is where the UIImage is attached to the SCNPlane.

```
let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: 0.2, height: 0.35)
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "we.jpg")
planeGeometry.materials = [material]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily replace SCNPlane's `.jpg` texture with `.gif` texture. But remember that in SceneKit there's no support for animated GIF textures.

Here's a code:

```
import ARKit
import SceneKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!   // in case you're using AR app
    //@IBOutlet var sceneView: SCNView!   // in case you're using VR app 
    let planeNode = SCNNode()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView.scene = scene
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true

        planeNode.geometry = SCNPlane(width: 0.2, height: 0.35)
        planeNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0,-0.5)
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {  // 3 sec delay
            let image = UIImage(named: "texture.jpg")
            self.planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = image
        }

        // Other stuff...
    }

    //...and you can replace a texture with a button's click:

    @IBAction func replaceTexture(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let image = UIImage(named: "texture.gif")
        planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = image
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting a runtime error at       let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView.  The error states its a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: `let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView` is a methodology primarily used in macOS SceneKit templates. Also you can use a popular UI approach – create your `sceneView` using `@IBOutlet` (I've put it in my code). For this just connect `ARSCNView` or `SCNView` from storyboard with a code in your `ViewController`. Also, you can create `sceneView` programmatically (so called API approach) – it looks like – `var sceneView = ARSCNView()` and then `self.view.addSubview(sceneView)`.